# Connect to RDS MySQL instance from ec2 Linux AMI - mysql command not found

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I try to connect to my RDS MySQL instance from an SSH connection to my ec2 server (through PUTTY) as outlined here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html#USER_ConnectToInstance.CLI

But I get:

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

I think maybe I have to install the MySQL Utility client on my ec2 linux server? If this is the case how do I do this?

I try to run the `mysql` command from my `/home/ec2-user` directory.

Comment: I expect a lot of programmers are given the task of getting a web-server going, so I understand why this was posted here; still, this question probably should have been posted on serverfault.com

Answer (score 12):

When using Amazon Linux 2 AMI, we need to install mysql. Use this command to install mysql on the instance:

```
sudo yum install mysql
```

And then you can connect using this command:

```
mysql -h change-to-your-rds-endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com -u <USER> -p
```

Answer (score 6):

Install mysql client on AWS Linux EC2: 
 `$ sudo yum install mysql`

Connect: 
 `$ mysql -h endpoint -P port -u masteruser -p`

If you enter your password and nothing happens, check your security groups. You may need to edit your inbound rules.

Answer (score 4):

First install mysql into your ec2 instace using below command
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`

After installing mysql try with below cmd to connect RDS

`mysql -h hostname -u username - p password`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install MySQL. Amazon AMIs use yum instead of apt so use:

```
sudo yum install mysql-server mysql-client
```

if you are working to setup a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) server then follow these instructions http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Answer (score 0):

Install the mysql client lib with the package manager of your system, for example on Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install mysqlclient
```

Comment: I'm using centOS so I think my command is `yum install mysql`. Also, I had to install all of mysql in order to get the mysql client. Isn't that a bit wasteful?

Comment: just install `mariadb`. That would be enough. No need to install the server.